# Why can my System (Dell Inspiron N4050) not connect to my WiFi any more? (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, broadcom, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron N4050 with dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. My Wireless Driver currently is Broadcomm in Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Just two days back, after downloading and installing pending updates in my Ubuntu 12.04, I am facing a peculiar problem. I use a Belkin N300 router in my home, and after providing the network password, it just goes on and on trying to connect to the network and eventually fails to do so! However, for the last year I had connected to my home network seamlessly and even now in Windows 7 or through my smartphone.

However, if i switch on the hotspot in my smartphone, Ubuntu connects with it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After some effortless research, I decided to remove the proprietary driver, and after a reboot, the connection could be established once again. (I think we have to wait for a driver update from Broadcomm.)

Comment: i removed the driver in question, bcmw-kernel-source, and rebooted and again reinstalled but to no effect!